# Create an anchor that will change the content when you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have content (with information) and links, how can I change the content when the  links above are clicked? Almost like a slider, but simple...
Can anyone show me an example?

[image]

Comment: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/OPgmPe

Comment: Examine how any tabs script works if you want examples. Questions like this are too broad for this site. This is not a tutorial service

Comment: @charlietfl ok man)) i'm just a beginner

Comment: Understand...irregardless no matter what level it is up to you to do your own research and ask questions when you have real code that is causing issues. This isn't a code writing service either. Read through the help center to get better understanding of how this site works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is show/hide your content when the links are clicked.

Check out the example below :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#one").show();
  $(".tile").click(function() {
    $(".tile").removeClass("selected");
    $(".content").slideUp(500);
    $("#" + $(this).data("link")).slideToggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.tile {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  border: 2px green solid;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 110px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile selected" data-link="one">One</div>
<div class="tile" data-link="two">Two</div>
<div class="tile" data-link="three">Three</div>
<hr/>
<div class="content" id="one">Content for #One Tile</div>
<div class="content" id="two">Content for #Two Tile</div>
<div class="content" id="three">Content for #Three Tile</div>
```

As you are new to jQuery do read these to understand what's happening in above example :

1. https://api.jquery.com/click/
2. https://api.jquery.com/slideup/
3. https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/
4. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you))) this is exactly)

Comment: last question, how default to show any content? 
for example, the design tab default to show in the beginning? in this code

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
$(".link_slide").click(function(){
  $(".content_slide").hide(500);
  $("#div"+$(this).attr("id")).show(500);
 });
```

```css
.content_slide{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="link_slide" href="#" id="one">One</a>
<a class="link_slide" href="#" id="two">Two</a>

<div class="content_slide" id="divone">First content</div>
<div class="content_slide" id="divtwo">Second content</div>
```